# How to create .ipa file in visual studio 2017(xamarin.ios)

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to Create IPA file in Visual Studio 2017 Cross platform app (Xamarin) And upload to appstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your build mode to Release, build your app, and then you can retrieve the .ipa file on your mac or on your PC. To make the directory where it is stored in appear on your mac, in visual studio just click the 'Show IPA File on Build Server' icon. Then use Application Loader to upload it to the App Store.

Comment: Where is the 'Show IPA File on Build Server' ?

Comment: @Christian It is in the visual studio toolbar, the icon looks like a piece of paper with the words 'IPA' on it. If its not there, right click the toolbar and make sure 'iOS' is checked.