# IPA file is not created in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, ipa

I have problem creating the IPA file for Xamarin.IOS project. 
In properties of the project i've selected the certificate and the provision and also selected the "create IPA file".
The build finishing succesfully but no IPA file there.
The project is on Release mode.
Any ideas?

I also tried to make archive from the Mac but i am getting errors "file not found" because the icons folder have extention of .app and its not recognised by Mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .ipa file in visual studio 2017(xamarin.ios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485129/how-to-create-ipa-file-in-visual-studio-2017xamarin-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Select Release (Solution Configuration)/iPhone (Solution Platform)/Remote Device, then right click on the iOS project and click on "Archive...".

The IPA is now building.

Answer (score 0):

In the following link of [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows), it shows you the steps you need to take for creating an IPA.

> - In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Xamarin.iOS project name and select Properties to open them for editing:
> - Select iOS IPA Options and select Ad-Hoc from the Configuration dropdown list:
> - If you are including an option iTunesMetadata.plist file, click the ... button, select it from the list and click the Open button:
> - You can optionally specify a Package Name for the IPA, if not specified it will have the same name as the Xamarin.iOS project.
> - Save your changes to the Project Properties.
> - Select Ad Hoc from the Build Configuration dropdown if it is available. Otherwise select Release:
> - Build the project to create the IPA package.
> - The IPA will be build in the Bin > iOS Device > Ad Hoc (or Release) folder:

Comment: There is no Ad-hoc option, i think this is an old option. Now it has only debug and release. I am using VS 2019

Comment: Then do the same in release mode, that would work too. I hope you have a MAC machine!

Comment: This what i am doing and of course i have a Mac machine.
Any other ideas?

Comment: What version of Xamarin are you carrying?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019
I manage to create the IPA file but only on MAC, on Windows i still have the problem

Comment: Could be a bug with VS2019, try putting this bug up!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug, turning the option off and on again for building the IPA file in IPA options worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've unistalled VS and installed again and the file created

Answer (score 0):

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_d8613546\ComponentModelCache
- Start Visual Studio
- Build the project
- the IPA created